# How to reference svg font defined inside a html document

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome

I want to make a single file html document which does not depend any other files.
The font-awesome contains an svg font which may be embedded in html document and reference in @font-face. but I don't know how to do this.

I just copied the svg into html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <metadata></metadata>
  <defs>
    <font id="fontawesomeregular" horiz-adv-x="1536">
      <font-face units-per-em="1792" ascent="1536" descent="-256" />
      <missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="448" />
      <glyph unicode=" " horiz-adv-x="448" />
      <glyph unicode="&#x09;" horiz-adv-x="448" />
      ....
      other more glyphs
    </font>
  </defs>
</svg>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

I also change the font-awesome.css file. change the  src property of @font-face to a uri

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: uri('fonts.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

but I got a large blank space and the font-awesome icon showed as a blank box.

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tQ6LS/

Comment: can you post your code here. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tQ6LS/

Comment: If you have found your answer, please post it below as an answer; don't edit it into the question, and don't put things like 'solved' in the question. Thanks!